# Why does Python on different computers have different issues with relative imports

Tags: python, relative-import

I am using python and I created a simple way to write HTML and output the file. I developed this module on 2 computers in which on the main one I could use the following according to the directory tree:

```
Pypertext:
   html.py
   widget.py
   htmlHeader.py
   htmlTitle.py
   htmlButton.py
```

This is the folder of the module that can be imported using:

```
from pyperclip.htmlHeader import Header
```

although in `htmlHeader.py` I have the following import:

```
from widget import baseWidget
```

This runs fine on my computer but when I go to the secondary computer I get an error and I fixed by:

```
from .widget import baseWidget
```

On my main computer I get an error for the attempted relative import and I feel that in the module script it should not have to be a lot of `try except` statements to make it work.
I use python 3.10

Comment: Do you run them any differently between the two computers (e.g. run one from an IDE and one from the command line)?  You could also put a print statement at the top to check the current working directory  `print(os.getcwd())` and see if that gives you a clue

Comment: Does Pypertext have an `__init__.py` file ? Strictly speaking relative imports are only intended inside a package, and it is only the existance of `__init__.py` file that defines a package.
Are your two computers different O/S or O/S versions - it could be a difference in O/S which explains why one relative import works.

You are correct that the the same code should work on every macine (unless the code is O/S dependent).

Comment: they both run in pycharm, they are both windows 10

Comment: there are no OS dependent modules in them and there is  `__init__.py`

Comment: What is the run configuration in pycharm?